# Microsoft Toolkit UWP DataGrid XAML control Highlight colour

Tags: datagrid, uwp

I am using UWP DataGrid, and I am looking for options to hide highlight color (Blue color) of [UWP DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics)?

Comment: I turned your link into a real link, and tried to make your question more readable. Please review my changes, and adapt as necessary.

Comment: Maybe try playing with one of these resource keys : https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml#L68

Comment: Which blue color? the border color within edit status ?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/color

To change your app's accent color, place the following code in app.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#00000000</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```